# Vertically justifying chapter number and name

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment

My thesis chapter are currently displayed as the image above, and I would like them to show as the image below, that is vertically justifying the name of the chapter according to the size of the number (happy to change the font sizes manually).
Furthermore, I would like to reduce the line spacing for the chapter title.

[image]

I am currently using the following code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\fontsize{80}{0}\selectfont \bfseries \raggedright}
    {\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{AB_gray_med}{|}\hsp}{0mm}{\LARGE \bfseries}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question correctly: the goal is that bottom of the last line of the title is aligned with the bottom of the number? What shall happen if there are any descending letters like `g`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `anyfontsize` (for the font dimension of 80), `tabularray`, and `titlesec` (for the title formatting):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}% <--- for testing purpose only

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{AB_gray_med}{gray}{0.75}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{}{0pt}{\begin{tblr}{
    vline{2}={AB_gray_med, wd=4pt},
    colspec={rX},
    colsep=10pt,
    column{1}={leftsep=0pt, font=\fontsize{80}{0}\selectfont \bfseries},
    column{2}={rightsep=0pt, font=\LARGE\bfseries},
    }
\SetCell[r=1]{h,r}\thechapter &  #1
\end{tblr}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}{}{}{0pt}{\LARGE\bfseries #1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My Chapter Title}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\chapter{The need for climate change adaptation in the UK}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only

\end{document}
```

Numberless title:

[image]

Title with one row:

[image]

Title with two rows:

[image]